# isomorphisms and homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

If I have some algebraic structure $V$ that can be provided with a non-trivial topology, is there a theorem that guarantees that if $V$ is isomorphic to $W$ then there exists a non-trivial topology on $W$ such that $(V, \tau_V)$ is homeomorphic to $(W, \tau_W)$ ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @SouravGhosh How are these Isomorphic as groups?

A (algebraic) Isomorphism $\phi:V\to W$ allways induces a topology on $W$. Just call a subset open iff the preimage along $\phi$ is open in $V$

Comment: @Alex Both are $\Bbb{Q}$ -vector spaces having same dimension, so corresponding abelian groups are isomorphic .

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In general, if you have a bijection $f:V\to W$ between $(V,\tau_V)$ a topological space and $W$ a set, the family $\tau_W =\{U\subseteq W : f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_V\}$ is a topology on $W$ and $f$ is a homeomorphism from $(V,\tau_V)$ to $(W,\tau_W)$ (you can check this directly). The topology $\tau_W$ is sometimes called the *direct image topology* on W *induced by* $f$.

In particular, if $f:V\to W$ is your isomorphism, you get that $\tau_W$ is a topology on $W$ and that $f$ is a homeomorphism between $V$ and $W$.